# how to fetch one row using where clause using procedure in 10.1.13-MariaDB in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Inside procedure code work well when I don't write in procedure . so what should I change into procedure it return only one row.

[image]

Result of procedure it return two row currently in my database have two rows.

[image]

Comment: Change the name of `emp_id` parameter to another (e.g.: `p_emp_id`).

Comment: I try this but not work. thanks for reply

Comment: See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1d4bea74282b46413711f46d5579914c) and [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=08b51ca2bc56771b7c8af362789e1b17).

Comment: Great job Sir, awesome suggestion sir. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Is `emp_id` both an argument to the Procedure and a column in the table?  That is very confusing, and leads to incorrect results.

I prefer to prefix arguments with `_` as a consistent way of distinguishing them.